# Is there a regex symbol to break the syntax into multiple lines?

Tags: linux, regex, syntax

**TLDR;**
Is there a symbol for breaking up a regex syntax into several lines?
In Bash, for example:

```
'{beginning och insanely long command \
  continuing on a second line}'
```

You use \ to split long lines and that's what I'm looking for.

**TL;**
I just found [QLogExplorer (*Cross-platform*)](https://github.com/rafaelfassi/qlogexplorer) and it seems to be just the log viewer I want. I've tried countless others and they all lack some function making them worthless in my eyes.
This one has a nice GUI and you can hide, colorize and define columns with regex.
I'm using the outstanding online tool [regex101](https://regex101.com) to create the syntax.
You run out of line real-estate fairly quickly and the syntax wraps around to the second line. But I loath word wrap something fierce so I would like to split the syntax after every capture group, or every new column in QLogExplorer, if you will.
Every hit I get on Gurgle is about defining end of line/string in your syntax and not for the syntax itself.

Please halp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(?x)` modifier, see [documentation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Your regex becomess:

```
'{(?x)beginning och insanely long command 
continuing on a second line}'
```